# How to use Airflow to process batch new data?

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

we want to use Airflow to process batch new data, first, our dag run a command to check our CRM system if there are new data every 15 minutes and then porcess the new data to two other systems, so it's like:

**task1** (check if there are new data) > **task 2** (send new data to system1) > **task 3** (send new data to system2)

The problem is

1. the numbers of new data are dynamic, we don't know how many data we
   might get.
2. how to porcess the new data one by one?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is the problem you face. Please be more specific.
The best bet is to create a custom operator(if there is no default one).

Task1(Extract new Data write to a location[Export as ndjson or other formats])> 
Task2(Checks if there are any data(if the location is dynamic pass it through xcom))> 
Task3(same as task 2(location may be passed as xcom))

Each run triggered every 15 min should fetch new data and push